# Makefile variable in commands?

Tags: makefile

I know that GNU make provides a way to reference targets and dependencies via `$^` and `$@`. Is there a way to reference actual command arguments? For example:

```
foo: bar
    myscript arg1 arg2 arg3
    ls arg3
```

I would like a way to execute `ls` with a variable that is the last argument from the line above. Obviously, I could define a variable `MYVAR := args`, but I was looking for a way to do this in make that would require manually defining the variable.

Comment: I doubt that any easier way exists. (And I think you meant "would *not* require...".)

Comment: No, there's no way of doing this – `make` is not a full-functional shell.  If you edit your question to illustrate the real situation, and so explain why you might want to do this, perhaps someone can suggest an alternative technique.

Comment: Just be a little more clear about Norman Gray's comment: make doesn't interpret or parse command lines in any way... except to replace variable references.  It simply takes the command line as a string and passes it to the shell for parsing.  Additionally, each line is passed to a _different_ invocation of the shell.  Since make doesn't parse the command line into arguments, it can't reference them in subsequent command lines.